# Binary file lost using svn merge

Tags: svn, branch, binaryfiles

I have two branch (let say branch A and branch B)in my svn repository
I'm done with one of them, branch B
I want to get changes of the other branch ,branch A.
On both branch i have binary files,in a separated folder.
When i try to get the new binary files of branch A, i get nothing, just tree conflict.

I use subclipse, merge a range of revision.
The branches was created with svn 1.4. Since the repository was moved to svn 1.6.

Comment: In addition i can say that the diff work just well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it was just a bug in the eclipse 's svn client
we need to manually select the revision we want and not let eclipse do it